# Custom Editor - How to add option to the settings list on a component

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is it possible to add an option to the settings list when you click on the settings icon on a component in the inspector?

[image: Image of settings drop down in the inspector]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don'T need a CustomEditor for this.

Simply use the [`[ContextMenu]` attribute](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ContextMenu.html) like

```c#
[ContextMenu("Example")]
private void SomeMethodWithoutParameters()
{
    // ...
}
```

[image]

---

If you are rather talking about adding an entry to an existing internal component you can use a generic [`[MenuItem]` instead](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MenuItem.html) starting with `CONTEXT/<ComponentName>` like

```c#
[MenuItem ("CONTEXT/Transform/Example")]
static void Example(MenuCommand command) 
{
    Transform transform = (Transform)command.context;

    // do something
}
```

**script has to be placed in a folder called `Editor`**

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to add this to all components of an object such as the transform?